# Почему min-width и и реальный width элемента не совпадают?

Tags: css, css3, вёрстка

Я задал свойство `min-width: 1020px` тегу `body`, чтобы появлялась полоса прокрутки сразу же после того, как это значение будет достигнуто.
Если интересует почему такое количество задано задано, то этому потому, что это получившиеся ширина сетки из элементов.
Пробовал через медиа-запрос таким же макаром:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1020px)
    body
        overflow-x: scroll
```

Но всё то же самое. Скролл включается тогда, когда у элемента 1044px, а у вьюпорта  1165px (тот, что показывает Хром, если правильно понимаю).

Ну и зачем тогда оно всё нужно? Но скорее всего я делаю что-то не так)

Как тогда контролировать скролл по ширине? Чтобы он включался ровно тогда, когда у body 1020px?

[image: Проблема]

Answer (score 1):

Скролл занимает пространство и отнимает ширину. Поэтому ширина `body` будет всегда меньше ширины окна браузера, если конечно это не мобильное устройство или не macOS. Также стоит помнить о том, что `body` имеет стандартный `padding` и `margin`. Обнулить его можно вот так:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Это я и так знал. Напишите лучше тогда, пожалуйста, как с такими очень важными знаниями написать медиазапрос.

Comment: 1044px - 15px (ширина полосы прокрутки в моем случае) = 1029px, а не 1020. В чем проблема?

Comment: @VostokSisters обнуляли стили для Body?

Comment: Обнулял, конечно же.